# Can't Set The Position of RightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set the position of the background layer like the position shown in the picture.

I tried to set the position of layer but I cannot.

```
func showRightNavBar()
{
    let inboxButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    inboxButton.setImage(UIImage (named: "email")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    inboxButton.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: -30)

    inboxButton.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.521568656, green: 0.1098039225, blue: 0.05098039284, alpha: 1)

    inboxButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(inboxButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    let qrButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    qrButton.setImage(UIImage (named: "QR-code")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

    qrButton.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 5, left: 17, bottom: 5, right: -7)

    qrButton.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7254902124, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.09803921729, alpha: 1)

    qrButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(qrButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    let fixSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    fixSpace.width = 10

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: qrButton),fixSpace,UIBarButtonItem(customView: inboxButton)]
}
```

I expect the background layer position will be like the position in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func showRightNavBar()
{
    let inboxButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    inboxButton.setImage(UIImage (named: "email")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    inboxButton.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: -30)
    inboxButton.contentEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: -37, bottom: 0, right: 20)

    inboxButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(inboxButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    let qrButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    qrButton.setImage(UIImage (named: "QR-code")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

    qrButton.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 5, left: 17, bottom: 5, right: -7)
    qrButton.contentEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: -20, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    qrButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(qrButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    let fixSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    fixSpace.width = 10

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: qrButton),fixSpace,UIBarButtonItem(customView: inboxButton)]
}
```

just need to set the contentEdgeInsets.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code.

- Your button's images sizes should be like :

  ```
  90 X 90 for 3x
  60 X 60 for 2x
  40 X 40 for 1x
  ```
- Check lines of code which has comment at the end of line.

  ```
  func showRightNavBar() {

       let inboxButton = UIButton(type: .system)
       inboxButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)) // Set frame of button
       inboxButton.setImage(UIImage (named: "email")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
       inboxButton.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 25, bottom: 0, right: -30) // Minor changes in insets
       inboxButton.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.521568656, green: 0.1098039225, blue: 0.05098039284, alpha: 1)
       inboxButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(inboxButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

       let qrButton = UIButton(type: .system)
       qrButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)) // Set frame of button
       qrButton.setImage(UIImage (named: "QR-code")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
       qrButton.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 5, left: 7, bottom: 5, right: -7) // Minor changes in insets
       qrButton.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7254902124, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.09803921729, alpha: 1)
       qrButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(qrButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

       let fixSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
       fixSpace.width = 10

       navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: qrButton),fixSpace,UIBarButtonItem(customView: inboxButton)]
  }
  ```

  After this, when I run, it give me this result :

[image: Right Bar Buttons]